# Manage folders on Web server

Tags: directory-structure

I am creating a dynamic Website using PHP with mysql. There are many sections in my website like internal-user-login-management, client-user-management, client-data, RBAC internal user, RBAC external user etc etc. I intend to use my own server. I am in lack of experience how to keep my pages in folder system at server? Kindly suggest. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
[Web Style Guide](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/3-site-file-structure.html)